# Rails 4, How to have a callback to a custom error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-errors, custom-error-handling

Below are some sudo code:

exceptions.rb

```
module Exceptions
  class CriticalError < StandardError
    # Question: How do I attach a callback to this error? Whenever this error is raised, I also want it to ping_me() as a after callback
    def ping_me()
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Desired outcome:

```
raise Exceptions::CriticalError # after a callback to this error being raised, it will run the ping_me() method
```

Question:

How do I do this in rails? I saw a `rescue_from` method but I think that is only available inside a controller

Thank you very much!

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to rescue and rethrow an exception? Are you asking how to use `pagerduty` to ping you? Or is it something else?

Comment: I am asking how to do this with custom error. For example, the code as it stands right now will raise an error and that's it. How do I make it so that it automatically rescues the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out

```
module Exceptions
  class CriticalError < StandardError
    def initialize(error_message)
      ping_me()
      super(error_message)
    end

    def ping_me()
      ....
    end
  end
end


raise Exceptions::CriticalError.new("something went wrong!")
```

Comment: What you wanted has nothing to do with rescuing the error. If this answer really works for you, then all you're doing is calling a method when the object is created. You don't even need the `raise` keyword. All you need to do is `Exceptions::CriticalError.new('foo')`.